# PHP Facebook SDK.About the access Token

Tags: php, facebook, sdk

Now I can get my own information such as my id,username.But when I use this access Token in order to get my friend lists,then the error is :
An active access token must be used to query information about the current user.
What is this mean?why the access Token doesn't work?
the first php:

```
$permissions = ['email']; // Optional permissions
$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('http://my_ip/facebook/login-callback.php', $permissions);
```

the second php:
(I can get my information)：

```
try {
   $response = $fb->get('/me');
   var_dump($response);
   echo "<br>";
   $userNode = $response->getGraphUser();
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookResponseException $e) {
// When Graph returns an error
echo 'Graph returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
exit;
} catch(Facebook\Exceptions\FacebookSDKException $e) {
// When validation fails or other local issues
echo 'Facebook SDK returned an error: ' . $e->getMessage();
exit;
}
//echo "<br>";
echo 'logged in as the id '.$userNode->getId()."<br>";
echo 'Logged in as ' . $userNode->getName()."<br>";
echo 'the user picture is '.$userNode->getPicture()."<br>";
$picture = $userNode->getPicture();
```

and:

```
$permissions = ['user_friends'];
$friendsUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('http://my_ip/facebook/friends-callback.php',$permissions);
```

finally,in the third php,I use the same way to get the information,but it is failed.

Comment: Please provide some source code

Comment: Can you edit your question, and add a source to it?

Comment: yes,I add the source.

Comment: hi,somebody help me?

Answer (score 0):

I think you missunderstood the concept of Facebook API.

First you have to get user permission to accept your request:

```
$permissions = ['email', 'user_friends']; // Permissions
$loginUrl = $helper->getLoginUrl('http://my_ip/facebook/login-callback.php', $permissions);
```

Then, in your `login-callback.php` file you can access the API according to requested permissions. For friends list:

```
$response = $fb->get('/me/friends');
var_dump($response);
```

You don't have to login every time after yout first request. The access token will be saved in session.

Comment: yes,I know,this is the first time I tried to get the friend lists.But it doesn't work either.So I changed my code and the request,I don't find the way to deal with it.Do you have any other examples?